# Where should I post about code readability?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm very interested on post some questions about code readability on several languages. With this I mean, I like to discuss about indentation, wrapping code, etc on several languages.

Thank you.

Comment: Code readability tends to be subjective and prone to discussion. Can you can post an example question that could be answered with facts?

Comment: Hey madth3, well, that is precisely what I want to. Instead of give you an code example, let me say that sometimes I find annoying to compare long lines of code with a difftool, when you can split it in several line improving the readability or, a classic example, should you try to over optimize some instruction just because you can see the matrix. That kind of thing I like to discuss.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try posting on [Code Review - Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), with the [readability](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/readability) tag.

Comment: Thank you Emmett, I'll do that